# Django app not visible in admin panel

Tags: django, admin, panel

I am using django 1.5.5,
My app admin.py contains,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from donors.models import EmailModel

admin.site.register(EmailModel)
```

my urls contains

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', home),
    .
    .
    .

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

my settings contains

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'donors',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

still I could not see my app "donors" inside django admin panel, did everything available on stack overflow, still I could not see the app. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Did you restart the runserver command manually? With such a change (adding a model to the admin interface), the automatic reload of the runserver is not enough. And are you able to access the admin interface? Do you login as a superuser? Where did you put admin.py? In the donors directory? Does it contain the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Use ModelAdmin to register donors model

Comment: @rajasimon: that is not necessary

Comment: @Peter Not necessary, but still to answer your question,                     1. Yes I restarted several times,                              2.donors directory contain __init__.py                                    3. I am able to login to admin panel using super user created at the time of syncdb. 4. admin.py located in app folder donors 5. donors is my app.

Comment: See your steps are right .. I think I have done them plenty of times. You are doing something wrong.
Share the project dir structure . specifically admin location

Answer (score 3):

Finally it works, I did a small mistake, mistakenly I created "**admin..py**" instead "**admin.py**".
I haven't recognize double '**.**' in file name.

but when I try to debug **admin.autodiscovery()**, in **import_module()** call to import donors.admin was failing, then I observer file name and change to appropriate "**admin.py**" then it works. Thank you guys for your time and apologies about wasting your time due to my silly mistake.